# I got problems with my reaction collector for my discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

i recently made a discord bot and added a special function that makes the bot collect a specific emoji in order to switch a page in an embed menu in dms of the bot. But it turned out to not really work so im asking here if someone can help me solve this.

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return ['➡️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id !== client.user.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 60000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What exactly isn't working? Is there an error? Try to elaborate so it's easier to help with your issue.

Comment: It was suppost to collect reactions on a bot message and send the collected amount in the console but it bugged out and sent "0 items collected" in the console when i reacted to the messages so do you have any idea of whats wrong and what could be changed?

Comment: It looks like your event handlers are correct, so it's probably an issue with the filter.
Try to use `reaction.emoji.toString()` instead of `reaction.emoji.name`. I'm guessing the name property returns the name of the emoji not the emoji itself, that's why your ➡️ reaction isn't collected.

Comment: Oh okay, ill try that